# Need to keep popout div open after HTML / PHP form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, jquery-animate

I have a pop-out div that opens when the user clicks on the div `#request-brochure-ribbon`. This works great. However, the pop-out holds a HTML form that submits to a PHP script. When the user does this, the pop-out div disappears and you have to click on it again to see the success message that the PHP script shows when the HTML form is submitted.

Using the below Javascript. Is there a way to modify it to keep the pop-out div out until they click the close button?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#request-brochure-ribbon').click(function(){
        $('#brochure-request-popout').animate({
            'right':'10px',
        },500);       
    });

    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('#brochure-request-popout').animate({
            'right':'-1500px'
        },500);
    });     
});
```

Comment: You have an ajax post? Or the page reloads after submit?

Comment: Can you make the popout div into an iframe?  That would be the easiest way.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your first `$('#brochure-request-popout').animate({'right':'10px',` <-- extra comma

Answer (score 1):

Your page probably reloads after the form is submitted, you are looking for ajax to submit your form: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/